# Yarn 3 - How to point installer to correct registry

Tags: yarnpkg-v2

In my current project which uses NPM Enterprise (i.e. has an internal npm registry), I'm following the steps to [migrate from Yarn Classic to Modern](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#step-by-step). Step 7 says to run `yarn install`. In doing so, the install fails because it's looking for a library in the public registry:

```
➤ YN0035: │ AppolloReact@npm:^2.3.21: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
➤ YN0035: │   Response Code: 404 (Not Found)
➤ YN0035: │   Request Method: GET
➤ YN0035: │   Request URL: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/AppolloReact
```

The Request URL should list our internal registry `https://npme.<name>.com`. I checked that npm has the correct registry by running

```
yarn config get registry
```

As an aside, YN0035 error code is not listed in the [Error Codes](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/error-codes/#gatsby-focus-wrapper) section, although I guess it means http error.

Anyone have experience with redirecting the installer to point to an internal registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For yarn modern, I learned the config param was renamed to `npmRegistryServer`. So to set/get, the command would be `yarn config set|get npmRegistryServer <url>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this just doesn't work currently. My investigation led me to this [issue thread](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1039) which was almost helpful.

All the advice in the thread works, assuming you fall into one of two categories:

1. Your private hosting is used for all dependencies (even if some are just mirroring, in the public case)
2. You're using a scoped dependency, e.g (@Scope/AppolloReact)

Using the `npmScopes` field, defining the registry there, will get you halfway. Then you need to `yarn login --scope @scope` and use your username, and either an API key or password. (I was using artifactory and used an API key tied to my SSO account).

Once that succeeds, a global `yarnrc.yml` will be created, for me in macOs it was `~/Users/<me>/.yarnrc.yml`

This will have the `npmAuthToken` field, which you can copy the value of and put into your project's `yarnrc.yml`.

Requiring a scope seems odd, but that seems to be the biggest blocker for me personally, and potentially yourself if i'm reading your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines in the yarn.lock that refer to the particular package and run `yarn install`. That's what fixed it for me.

My interpretation of what is going on:
There seems to be nothing wrong with continuing to refer to a package in a private registry by url in the package.json.

It's rather that `yarn install` at this point in the migration process is supposed to update the `yarn.lock` file. But unfortunately something seems to not work in interpreting the old data in the `yarn.lock` for such a package. Removing these lines in the lock file forces yarn to generate them fresh based on the package.json.